# Setting up self-signed ssl on subdomain: servers certificate does not match URL

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to set up ssl for owncloud on an Ubuntu 14 LTS server. The domain is served by the same company that hosts the nameserver for the domain, but a single subdomain foo.bar.com is directed to a server in our office (technically a router, but that should hardly matter I think). I wish to use a self-signed certificate to secure the connection, because installing the certificate to clients is feasable. Owncloud is set up as a virtualhost in apache2.

My problem is that I have tried every combination of common name for the certificate: foor.bar.com, bar.com, *.bar.com, but every time I get the error, that the server's certificate does not match the URL.

What could I be doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you upload the certificate to pastebin ?

Comment: @GaborVincze http://pastebin.com/U9S3jy8k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that my certificate was only signed for server usage while any other site (e.g. say google), signed it for server and client usage. So instead of using the easy-rsa build-key-server, I tried another walkthrough using openssl, which signed it a bit differently, this seems to have solved the problem.